# Переменная cash_or_card не привязывается к радиокнопкам

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Переменная `Cash_or_card` должна изменяться автоматически когда меняется выбор с помощью радиокнопки. Но ничего не происходит! Что не так?

```
<form method="POST" class="form-inline">
      <div class="btn-group " data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default active" >
                  <input type="radio" v-model="cash_or_card" value="cash" checked> <i class="fa fa-btn fa-rub"></i>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default" >
                  <input type="radio" v-model="cash_or_card" value="card"> <i class="fa fa-btn fa-credit-card"></i>
            </label>
      </div>

      <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit"  @click.prevent="submitOrder()" value="отправить">
</form>  

var vue = new Vue({
       el: '#app', 
           data: {
               cash_or_card: "cash",
           });
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

Приведенный вами код не полный — не хватает обертки с *id="app"*, нет всех свойств у Vue и синтаксическая ошибка, связанная с этим.

В коде ниже переменная меняется, это легко можно заметить, если просто вывести ее на экран.

Кстати, `checked` не нужно ставить, Vue сделает работу за вас, ведь начальное значение инпута вы задаете в объекте *data*.

```js
var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    cash_or_card: "cash"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id=app>
  <form method="POST" class="form-inline">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" v-model="cash_or_card" value="cash"> <i class="fa fa-btn fa-rub"></i>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" v-model="cash_or_card" value="card"> <i class="fa fa-btn fa-credit-card"></i>
      </label>
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" @click.prevent="submitOrder()" value="отправить">
  </form>

  <output>{{ cash_or_card }}</output>
</div>
```

Comment: В целом насколько я понял получались кнопки, и соответственно пришлось в ручную написать обработчик события click, если input просто без кнопки то всё работает

Comment: Кажется, ваш комментарий особенно не имеет связи с вашим изначальным вопросом )